# How to count data in Related Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to count value of related model, but i am unable to count, Please let me know where i am Mistaking..

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length= 225)
    slug=models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)

class Detail(models.Model):
    project = models.OneToOneField('Project', related_name='detailsofpro', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    possession = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, choices=(('Under Construction', 'Under Construction'),('New launch', 'New Launch'),('Ready To Move', 'Ready To Move')))
```

here is my `views.py` file..

```
def admin_view(request):
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('project_details').annotate(Count('possession'))
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'project': project})
```

here is my `index.html` frile

```
<p>{{project.project_details.possession.count}}</p>
```

i want to count `possession` from `details` model, please let me know how i can count

Comment: What do you mean with "count `possession`"? What is the difference with counting the number of `Detail`s?

Comment: Your `project` is furthermore not a *single* `Project`, but a `QuerySet` of *all* `Projects`, so the name `project` does not make much sense, neither does `{{ project }}`, or similar things.

Comment: actually i want to count that how many `projects` are `Under Construction` in `possession` fields in `details` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `.prefetch_related(…)`, the `.annotate(…)`. What you can do is here make an aggregate per value of `Posession`:

```
def admin_view(request):
    possessions = Detail.objects.values('possession').annotate(
        nprojects=Count('project')
    ).order_by('possession')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'possessions': possessions})
```

In the template, you can then iterate over the records:

```
{% for item in possessions %}
    {{ item.possession }}: {{ item.nprojects }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: and when i will do if i want to count `available_for` field also in `Detail` model...

Comment: You can use a similar technique where you replace `possession` with `available_for` in `.values(..)`, `.order_by(..)` and in the template.

Comment: you mean to say i will need to create another query for this...

Comment: @msginfosys: yes.

Comment: could it be possible in the same query, because both fields are available in same model...

Comment: @msginfosys: no, since in order to count, it performs a `GROUP BY`, and this thus means that if we do it in one query, the `GROUP BY`, would "span" both fields, and then we get the count *per* `possession` and *per* `available_for`.